# Using customuserservice sample of Identity Server V3 in MVC not able to redirect to login page

Tags: thinktecture-ident-server, thinktecture-ident-model, thinktecture, identityserver3

I am using CustomUserService sample of Identity server v3. I added home controller as below - `public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        //ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        //return View();
        return View((User as ClaimsPrincipal).Claims);

    }`
```

And added 2 views About.cshtml and Index.cshtml.
As you see About action has Authorize attribute. So when I navigate to About, I should get redirected to login page of Identity Server V3 however it is not happening so. My complete startup.cs is as follows -

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        LogProvider.SetCurrentLogProvider(new DiagnosticsTraceLogProvider());

        app.Map("/core", coreApp =>
        {
            var factory = InMemoryFactory.Create(
                clients: Clients.Get(),
                scopes: Scopes.Get());

            // different examples of custom user services
            var userService = new RegisterFirstExternalRegistrationUserService();
            //var userService = new ExternalRegistrationUserService();
            //var userService = new EulaAtLoginUserService();
            //var userService = new LocalRegistrationUserService();

            factory.UserService = new Registration<IUserService>(resolver => userService);

            var options = new IdentityServerOptions
            {
                //IssuerUri = "https://idsrv3.com",
                IssuerUri = "https://localhost:44333/",
                SiteName = "Thinktecture IdentityServer3 - CustomUserService",
                //SigningCertificate = LoadCertificate(),
                SigningCertificate = Certificate.Get(),
                Factory = factory,
                CorsPolicy = CorsPolicy.AllowAll,

                AuthenticationOptions = new Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Configuration.AuthenticationOptions
                {
                    IdentityProviders = ConfigureAdditionalIdentityProviders,
                    LoginPageLinks = new LoginPageLink[] { 
                        new LoginPageLink{
                            Text = "Register",
                            //Href = "~/localregistration"
                            Href = "localregistration"
                        }
                    }
                },

                EventsOptions = new EventsOptions
                {
                    RaiseSuccessEvents = true,
                    RaiseErrorEvents = true,
                    RaiseFailureEvents = true,
                    RaiseInformationEvents = true
                }
            };

            coreApp.UseIdentityServer(options);
        });
```

I am using CustomerUserService sample because, I want to use WSfederation. So ADFS wil provide claims to identity server and in turn Identity server should return those claims to About view.
Can anyone help me here.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar situation, when there were errors during Identity Server initialization. I turned on logging in Web.config:

http://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docs/configuration/logging.html

```
    <system.diagnostics>
      <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
       <listeners>
        <add name="myListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="d:\logs\STS.log" />
        <remove name="Default" />
       </listeners>
      </trace>
     </system.diagnostics>
```

Logs showed me that my certificate's key length was less than 2048 bits. You might have run into a different error which is logged as well.